# Dynamic Allocation and Reallocation of Memory in a Tree Algorithm

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, realloc

I am programming a tree algorithm for simulations. Every processor has its own tree. At a specific point in the program I have to check if there are particles in a specific tree which do not belong there. I collect them and send them to the right tree / processor.

My question is about the process where I collect the particles and put them into lists of dynamic size. Since the number of particles I have to send to another tree is not constant, I have to work with dynamic arrays.

I implemented a small program where all this should happen. But it works only for small `N`. But also for small `N` there are sometimes errors. The reallocation process does probably not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DIM 2

// Struct for particles
typedef struct {
    double m;
    double x[DIM];
    int id;
} Particle;

// Structs for lists I want to fill with particle data
typedef struct {
    double **list; // every processor has its own list
    int *counter; // length of the list
} ParticleList;

void generateParticles(Particle *p, int N);
void buildList(Particle *p, ParticleList *plist, int numprocs, int N);

int main() {
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));

    // Generate and print data
    int N = 3;
    Particle *p = (Particle*)malloc(N * sizeof(*p));
    generateParticles(p, N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("id: %d m: %lf x: %lf %lf\n", p[i].id, p[i].m, p[i].x[0], p[i].x[1]);
    }

    // Fill lists
    int numprocs = 4;
    ParticleList plist;
    plist.list = malloc(sizeof(double*) * numprocs);
    // At the beginning every list should be of size zero
    // Therefore I initialize lists for every processor of size zero
    for (int k = 0; k < numprocs; k++)
        plist.list[k] = malloc(sizeof(double) * 0);
    plist.counter = calloc(numprocs, sizeof(int));
    // Fill the lists randomly
    buildList(p, &plist, numprocs, N);

    for (int k = 0; k < numprocs; k++) {
        printf("%d\n", plist.counter[k]);
        for (int c = 0; c < (DIM * plist.counter[k]); c++) {
            printf("%lf ", plist.list[k][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(p);
    return 0;
}

void buildList(Particle *p, ParticleList *plist, int numprocs, int N) {
    for (int k = 0; k < numprocs; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (rand() % 10 < 3) { // randomly choose particles to fill the list
                plist->counter[k]++;
                // Here might be the problem?
                plist->list[k] = realloc(plist->list[k], DIM * sizeof(plist->list[k]));
                for (int j = plist->counter[k]; j < (plist->counter[k] + DIM); j++)
                    plist->list[k][j] = p[i].x[j];
            }
        }
    }
}

void generateParticles(Particle *p, int N) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int d = 0; d < DIM; d++) {
            p[i].x[d] = rand() % 10;
        }
        p[i].m = rand() % 10;
        p[i].id = i;
    }
}
```

The problem is probably in this line: `plist->list[k] = realloc(plist->list[k], DIM * sizeof(plist->list[k]));`

I get the following error:

```
*** Error in `./append_struct': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x00000000015df540 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fc931b3e7e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x834aa)[0x7fc931b4a4aa]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(realloc+0x179)[0x7fc931b4b839]
./append_struct[0x400b5e]
./append_struct[0x4009bf]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fc931ae7830]
./append_struct[0x4007b9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3670408                            /home/exp/append_struct
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 08:02 3670408                            /home/exp/append_struct
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 08:02 3670408                            /home/exp/append_struct
015df000-01600000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fc92c000000-7fc92c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc92c021000-7fc930000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc9318b1000-7fc9318c7000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 4985364                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fc9318c7000-7fc931ac6000 ---p 00016000 08:02 4985364                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fc931ac6000-7fc931ac7000 rw-p 00015000 08:02 4985364                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fc931ac7000-7fc931c87000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 4994073                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fc931c87000-7fc931e87000 ---p 001c0000 08:02 4994073                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fc931e87000-7fc931e8b000 r--p 001c0000 08:02 4994073                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fc931e8b000-7fc931e8d000 rw-p 001c4000 08:02 4994073                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fc931e8d000-7fc931e91000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc931e91000-7fc931ea9000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 4994056                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7fc931ea9000-7fc9320a8000 ---p 00018000 08:02 4994056                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7fc9320a8000-7fc9320a9000 r--p 00017000 08:02 4994056                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7fc9320a9000-7fc9320aa000 rw-p 00018000 08:02 4994056                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7fc9320aa000-7fc9320ae000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc9320ae000-7fc9320d4000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 4994051                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fc9322b5000-7fc9322b8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc9322d0000-7fc9322d3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc9322d3000-7fc9322d4000 r--p 00025000 08:02 4994051                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fc9322d4000-7fc9322d5000 rw-p 00026000 08:02 4994051                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fc9322d5000-7fc9322d6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffc92bdb000-7ffc92bfc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffc92bfc000-7ffc92bfe000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffc92bfe000-7ffc92c00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Edit:

My example code is just a rough sketch and I consider myself as a beginner in C. This is probably the reason why my question is not really clear. In my actual code I am building a tree structure with my particles (Quadtree in 2D and Octree in 3D) on every processor. Every processor has other particles. I identify wrong particles using their position within the tree in a recursive tree walk and send them to other processors since I want compact tree structures. In order to do that I have to put wrong particles into a list which I can then pass to the MPI library in order to send the data to other processors. The number of particles is normally much larger than the number of processors (N >> numProc).

Comment: "does not work" isn't a helpful problem description. State clearly and specifically what error or symptom you are observing.

Comment: Please define "does not work". Does your program compile? If not, what error message do you get? Does it run? What is the exepected output and the actual output? Etc.?

Comment: why, we don't have anymore 5 minute to correct an edit ? my bad.

Comment: @kaylum I improved my question.

Comment: Here `plist->list[k][j] = p[i].x[j]` j goes up to `plist->counter[k] + DIM - 1`, but only space for `DIM * sizeof(plist->list[k])` was reserved. `sizeof(plist->list[k])` is wrong anyway, should be `sizeof(plist->list[k][0])` afaics.

Comment: Call me hard-deaded, but I don't understand why you have a `ParticleList` with no `Particle`s in it.

Comment: @Michaël Roy I need lists of particles to send these Particles to other processors using MPI. What would be your approach. Maybe my approach is not the best.

Comment: @Ctx With your help the program runs as desired. Thank you! Can you tell me if `free(plist)` is enough to deallocate the memory correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your reasoning, it would maybe work for optimizing computation speed, but you'd need to have a working program to contemplate doing that.

Also, your algorithm for distributing particles to processors doesn't work.  As it is written, particles have a 70% chance of not being allocated to any list.

In your declaration for the list of particles:

```
typedef struct {
    double **list; // a list of double* ?  It's going to be hard to find which double
                   // belongs to which Particle, this makes your app more confusing
                   // and much harder to write than it ought to.
    int *counter;  // a length of lengths?  what's its length?
} ParticleList;
```

You should consider doing something like this instead. This would probably work better, I've omitted error-checking on the result of calloc(), which you should always do.  I've chosen calloc(), because it clears the memory it allocates.

```
typedef struct {
  struct Particle* next;
  double m;
  double x[DIM];
  int id;
} Particle;

typedef struct Particle* ParticleList;

// this should look familiar to you.
void insert_particle(ParticleList* list, struct Particle* part)
{
  part->next = NULL;  // just to make sure we don't introduce bugs here
  if (*list == NULL)
  {
    *list = part;
    return;
  }
  struct Particle* p = *list;
  while (p)
  {
    if (p->next == NULL)
    {
      p->next = part
      return;
    }
    p = p->next;
  }
}

int main()
{
   int i;
   int numProcs = 4;
   int assigned_proc;
   int N = 3;  // less particles than threads?  This does not sound right...
   // ...
   // allocate empty lists and all particles.
   ParticleList* procparts = calloc(numprocs, sizeof(ParticleList));
   struct Particle* particles = calloc(N, sizeof(struct Particle));

   for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)                        // for each particle ...
   {
     // initialize particle location...
     particles[i].id = i;
     // ... and x[]...

     assigned_proc = rand() % numprocs;           // pick a processor...

     insert_particle(&procparts[assigned_proc], &particles[i]);
   }

   // ...
}
```

Note that this implementation does not require any call to realloc() during execution.

Once your app works using 'normal' threads, it will be much simpler to make it MPI compatible.

Comment: I updated my question to make my problem more clear. Normally `N` is much bigger than `numProcs`. That was just an example. I do not understand what happens in your function `insert_particle()`. In order to use `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Receive()` I thought that I would need for every processor arrays of particles and the length of that array. Am I wrong?

Comment: No you're not.  But how will you find which double belongs to which particle when comes the time to switch?

Comment: I do not understand your last question. Can you please explain the problem you see more clearly to me?

Comment: In your original question, you said you had to switch particle data between MPI jobs on a regular basis.  You will have to rebuild your arrays of floats at that point.  You cannot just stuff doubles in an MPI buffer without keeping track of which particles they belong to.  That bookkeeping _is_ the most challenging aspect of the project.